# Manual wp_install() difficulties

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to automatically install a WordPress distribution in PHP with the following code:

```
$base_dir = '/home/username/wordpress_location';
chdir($base_dir);

define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.domain.com/');
define('WP_INSTALLING', true);

require_once 'wp-load.php';
require_once 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
require_once 'wp-includes/wp-db.php';
$result = wp_install($title, $username, $email, true, null, $password);
```

When I manually run **wp_install()** [*/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php*], I get this error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function flush_rules() on a non object in /home/username/public_html/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php on line 85`

After looking at the [WordPress source code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php#L85), it appears that **$wp_rewrite** is trying to call **flush_rules()** when **$wp_rewrite** itself doesn't exist.

Another strange twist is that this is virtually the same code as [wordpress-cli-installer](https://github.com/nexcess/wordpress-cli-installer/blob/master/wordpress-cli-installer.php#L304). My wp-config.php file is automatically generated and ready.

How come wordpress-cli-installer's code works but mine does not?

### EDIT:

After a lot of trial and error, I found out that my code was not working because it was defined and executed in a function. After I separated the code from the function and executed it, it worked. However, that raises another question. Is it even possible to execute the above code *inside* of a function? I have tried using the `$GLOBALS += get_defined_vars();` hack after the **require_once** statements, but that doesn't seem to do anything. In other words:

```
<?php

$base_dir = '/home/username/wordpress_location';
chdir($base_dir);

define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.domain.com/');
define('WP_INSTALLING', true);

require_once 'wp-load.php';
require_once 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
require_once 'wp-includes/wp-db.php';
$result = wp_install($title, $username, $email, true, null, $password);

// ^ This works.
// v This won't work.

function run(){
    $base_dir = '/home/username/wordpress_location';
    chdir($base_dir);

    define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.domain.com/');
    define('WP_INSTALLING', true);

    require_once 'wp-load.php';
    require_once 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
    require_once 'wp-includes/wp-db.php';
    $result = wp_install($title, $username, $email, true, null, $password);
}
run();

?>
```

Comment: `My wp-config.php file is automatically generated and ready` does it have `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');` in it? `$wp_rewrite` is initialized in that file.

Comment: @Cheery My wp-config.php file has the line `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');`

Comment: Try to var_dump($wp_rewrite); after each require_once. Your error message means that $wp_rewrite is not defined. It should be defined if wp-settings.php is loaded.

Comment: @Cheery Thanks. Your advice helped me locate the first issue.

Comment: did you ever get this to install from a function or did you stick with   placing the code outside the function?

Comment: @Eli I got this to install inside of the function.

Comment: How did you approach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`How do I use the require_once inside of a function while still being able to access and manage the globals?` 
That idea is wrong in general. You can make global only required variables (which might change from version to version). But the 'dirty' way is

```
function make_global()
{
    $test_var = "I'm local";
    $GLOBALS += get_defined_vars();
}
var_dump(isset($test_var));
make_global();
var_dump(isset($test_var));
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not being clear. I reworded the second question.

Comment: @GatorAlli  Could you show the whole code? I do not want to be guessing, because the example I provided is working fine.

Comment: @GatorAlli  could you check after each require_once that local $wp_rewrite exists? and than, after the 'hack' check that it is available in the global scope.