# How to use PHP in a Phing build file correctly?

Tags: php, phing

I am writing PHP directly inside a Phing *build.xml* file using `adhoc-task`.

The following does work but throws up console errors:

```
<adhoc-task name="foo"><![CDATA[

 define('WP_INSTALLING', true);

 require_once '${build.dir.wp}/wp-load.php';
 require_once '${build.dir.wp}/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
 require_once '${build.dir.wp}/wp-includes/wp-db.php';

 $result = wp_install( 'title', 'admin', 'admin@example.com');

]]></adhoc-task>
```

*The error: The adhoc class you defined must be an instance of phing.Task BUILD FAILED.The adhoc class you defined must be an instance of phing.Task*

But it still works...

If I wrap the PHP in a class it doesn't work at all:

```
<adhoc-task name="foo"><![CDATA[

   class FooTest extends Task {
   //php code ....
   }
]]></adhoc-task>
```

*The error: You must define at least one class for AdhocTaskdefTask.*

What is the proper way to include PHP inside the build file (without having access to the php/phing/tasks folder)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `test/etc/regression/299/build.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="test" default="main">

  <target name="main">
    <bar/>
  </target>

  <adhoc-task name="bar"><![CDATA[
      class BarTask extends Task {
          function main() {
              print("BarTask: success!\n");
          }
      }
  ]]></adhoc-task>

</project>
```

Comment: Thanks I did not notice `<bar/>` in the docs, the errors are gone, but now the problem is that it doesn't work at all, for example https://gist.github.com/3766989 , is there something simple I am missing?

Comment: use `-verbose` and `-debug` options on the CLI to see where it fails.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is with several globals varibales in the include files, as seen here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136073/manual-wp-install-difficulties . Is there any way to just run raw php outside a function using `<adhoc-task>`?